# Бесплатный сертификат от Comodo и PHP stream_socket_server

Tags: php, websocket, openssl

Есть бесплатный SSL сертификат от Comodo, в формате crt. Однако!  stream_socket_server в php понимает только в формате *.pem Команда для конвертациия, выдает:

```
root@noc:/usr/local/www/apache24/ssl/data/service # openssl x509 -inform der -in noc_wdwedwe_ru.crt -out noc_wdwedwe_ru.pem
unable to load certificate
34379270664:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1201:
34379270664:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:374:Type=X509
```

Сиё нужно для поднятия сервера websocket со связкой: сервер на php <--> Javascript в браузере, без ругательств на самоподписный сертификат.

Код на php:

```
$ip="noc.wdwedwe.ru";             
$port="8100"; 
$pem_file = "noc_wdwedwe_ru.pem";     
$context = stream_context_create();
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem_file);  // Our SSL Cert in PEM format        
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer_name', false);
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'ciphers', 'ALL'); 
 $socket = stream_socket_server("ssl://{$ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context); 
stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, false);    
$socket = setupTcpStreamServer($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $ip, $port);    
if (!$socket) {die("$errstr ($errno)\n");}
echo "--демон сервера стартовал\n";
$connects = array();

while (true) {
    //формируем массив прослушиваемых сокетов:
    $read = $connects;
    $read []= $socket;
    $write = $except = null;
    if (!stream_select($read, $write, $except, null)) {break;}
    if (in_array($socket, $read)) {
    $connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, -1);
    if ($connect==true){
        $info = handshakeSocket($connect);
        if ($info==true){
            $connects[] = $connect;//добавляем его в список необходимых для обработки
            onOpen($connect, $info);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий            
        };
    };

        unset($read[ array_search($socket, $read) ]);
    }
    foreach($read as $connect) {//обрабатываем все соединения
        $data = fread($connect, 100000);
        if (!$data) { //соединение было закрыто 
            fclose($connect);
            unset($connects[ array_search($connect, $connects) ]);
            onClose($connect);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий
            continue;
        }
        onMessage($connect, $data,$info);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Может ошибку выдает потому, что der - это не есть формат, сопоставимый с crt? der - это бинарный формат, поэтому он и не может подгрузить для конвертации Ваш crt-файл. Попробуйте конвертацию командой:

```
openssl x509 -in noc_wdwedwe_ru.crt -out noc_wdwedwe_ru.pem
```

А crt и pem форматы идентичны. Просто в pem можно запихнуть еще и ключ и вообще несколько сертификатов по порядку один под другим. В Вашем же случае, так как отдельного файла с ключом нет и сертификат один, pem файл будет полностью идентичен файлу crt. Т.е. достаточно будет простого переименования расширения файла из crt в pem.

Comment: Да, так пробовал. Но, скрипт выдает ошибку: PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): Unable to set private key file `/usr/local/www/apache24/ssl/data/service/noc_wdwedwe_ru.pem' in /usr/local/www/apache24/ssl/data/service/ssl_test2.php on line 34. на stream_cocket_accept

Comment: Рецепт: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1143/66/creating-a-pem-file тоже не работает

Comment: @Pavel Gribov Ну так я же упомянул про файл с ключом. Если он есть -  присобачьте еще и его в этот pem-файл. Ну а если файл с ключом отсутствует, то, как говорится, "На нет и суда нет".

Comment: Comodo выдает noc_wdwedwe_ru.crt и noc_wdwedwe_ru.ca-bundle

Comment: @Pavel Gribov Еще раз... У Вас есть key-файл?

Comment: Comodo выдает noc_wdwedwe_ru.crt и noc_wdwedwe_ru.ca-bundle, соответственно key файла нет.

Comment: @Pavel Gribov Но когда Вы получали сертификат у Comodo они же просили у Вас csr-файл? А csr-файл генерился при помощи key-файла. Т.е. у Вас должен быть key-файл.